# activation of network connection failed for ethernet, ubuntu 20.04, dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I have seen other posts that are similar to my situation but I think I am really confused at to why I get network connection failed.

I have a dual boot, Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

I do not have any problems so far.

I did not install anything new but yesterday Ubuntu started to give me the Network Connection failed prompt.

I had disabled fast boot even before the installation of Ubuntu.
I have tried rebooting the router.
I have tried apt-get update and install reinstall network-manager.

Internet works fine in Windows 10. I only use Ethernet cable.

Trying some commands from other posts shows:

```
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::2490:162a:b1d0:593c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:3f:49:81:07:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1183  bytes 184860 (184.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 571  bytes 87423 (87.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7f00000-f7f20000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3797  bytes 301360 (301.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3797  bytes 301360 (301.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ cat etc/network/interfaces
cat: etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ cat etc/resolv.conf
cat: etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for theocharis: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: e0:3f:49:81:07:04
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-25-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff memory:f7f39000-f7f39fff ioport:f040(size=32)
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ ping www.ku.edu
ping: www.ku.edu: Temporary failure in name resolution
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ ping www.ku.edu
PING ku.edu (129.237.11.76) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

Sorry if I am not providing enough information. Forum posts really confuse me and I do not have enough experience.

1. Edit for @galexite
   @galexite I used my phone for USB tethering and got:

```
theocharis@theocharis:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep e1000e
[    0.530758] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    0.530759] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.530887] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    0.618026] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    0.696624] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) e0:3f:49:81:07:04
[    0.696626] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    0.696664] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    0.697382] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    9.384850] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[    9.384854] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

2. Edit for @waltinator I got:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2021-06-27 18:12:19 EEST, end at Tue 2021-08-10 23:35:47 EEST. --
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3754] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first ti>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3754] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3945] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManag>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3973] manager[0x55bb0c56a030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/l>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3973] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4722] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4722] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "theocharis"
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4725] dns-mgr[0x55bb0c554290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=sy>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4728] manager[0x55bb0c56a030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4728] manager[0x55bb0c56a030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4765] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Ne>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4772] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Ne>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4786] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Ne>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4790] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Net>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4802] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/N>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4805] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by st>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4806] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by sta>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4807] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4808] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4814] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linu>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4814] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4814] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <warn>  [1628626296.4815] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4840] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4842] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManage>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4852] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkMan>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4861] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'ma>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <warn>  [1628626296.6773] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.6808] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Αυγ 10 23:11:40 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626300.4897] agent-manager: agent[11acc7c7347d05d5,:1.42/org.gnome.Shell.Netwo>
lines 1-33...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Sun 2021-06-27 18:12:19 EEST, end at Tue 2021-08-10 23:35:47 EEST. --
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3754] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first tim>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3754] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns->
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3945] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManage>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3973] manager[0x55bb0c56a030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/li>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.3973] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4722] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4722] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "theocharis"
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4725] dns-mgr[0x55bb0c554290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=sym>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4728] manager[0x55bb0c56a030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4728] manager[0x55bb0c56a030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4765] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Net>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4772] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Net>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4786] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Net>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4790] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Netw>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4802] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Ne>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4805] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by sta>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4806] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by stat>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4807] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4808] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4814] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4814] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4814] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <warn>  [1628626296.4815] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4840] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4842] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4852] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkMana>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.4861] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'man>
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <warn>  [1628626296.6773] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Αυγ 10 23:11:36 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626296.6808] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Αυγ 10 23:11:40 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626300.4897] agent-manager: agent[11acc7c7347d05d5,:1.42/org.gnome.Shell.Networ>
Αυγ 10 23:11:41 theocharis NetworkManager[759]: <info>  [1628626301.5521] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
```

Comment: Can you try to connect to the Internet (i.e. by plugging in the cable), then run `dmesg | grep e1000e`, and add that to your question?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

The e1000e driver has a known issue pertaining to your network card’s powersaving feature which is activated by the Windows driver. You need to reset the PCIe device to continue using it in Linux.

The steps are outlined here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620766

This needs to be done every time after starting Windows.

You should also report a kernel bug, if there is not already one.

Comment: before doing this i have to ask, i use a pci to m.2 adapter for my booting device. is this pcie device reset going to interfere with this? thank you for your help!

Comment: @xapnsma, the honest answer is I don’t know, but this sounds unlikely. This is a temporary reset. Rebooting the machine requires another reset, so the procedure is at most temporary.